# Python Pandas.Series.asof: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'struct_time'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm encountering a problem passing a `datetime` into a `Pandas.Series.asof`:

```
def valueAsOf(self, date):
    if type(date) is str:
        return time.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
    return self.__series.index.asof(date)
```

and the following error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/test.py", line 106, in <module>
    print someTs.series.asof('20150101')
  File "/Users/x/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2460, in asof
    if where < start:
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 836, in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__ (pandas/tslib.c:15612)
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'struct_time'
```

Currently the index of the `pandas.Series` is `<type 'time.struct_time'>`

Will the problem be solved by converting `date` from `struct_time` to `Timestamp`? If so, how can this be done?

---

I tried converting `date` to a `datetime` object but still received the same error message, even though `type(dt)` shows that its `<type 'datetime.datetime'>`

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(date))
return self.__series.index.asof(dt)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandas time Series should *always* have an index of type `DatetimeIndex`.
The `TypeError` you posted,
can be reproduced if the Series index is a plain `Index` of dtype `object` containing `time.struct_time`s.

For example, this reproduces the TypeError:

```
import datetime as DT
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.date_range('2015-1-1', '2015-1-5', freq='D')
index = [date.timetuple() for date in x.to_pydatetime()]
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(len(index)), index=index)
try:
    print(ts.asof('20150101'))
except TypeError as err:
    print(err)
```

yields

```
Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'struct_time'
```

The problem can be fixed by converting `ts.index` to a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
ts.index = pd.to_datetime([DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(item)) 
                           for item in ts.index])
```

Then

```
print(ts.asof('20150101'))
```

prints the value of `ts` associated with the date `20150101`:

```
0
```

Better yet, don't use timetuples. Convert the sequence of dates to a
DatetimeIndex as early as possible:

```
In [59]: pd.to_datetime(['20150101'])
Out[59]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any advantage to using an index made of dtype `object` containing `time.struct_time`s when dealing with time series?

Comment: No, a Pandas `Index` of object dtype is the catch-all index class used when the index values do not fit a more specialized index type. The `object` dtype indicates that the values are arbitrary Python objects. When possible use `pd.DatetimeIndex` for datetimes. All Pandas methods that rely on time-based indexing (such as interpolation, and `asof`) expects the index to be a `DatetimeIndex`.